# No Longer Able to Authenticate to SharePoint

Tags: list, authentication

For several years, I have had a PowerShell script that has been able to connect to a SharePoint site just fine to read and work with a list. Last week we started getting this error:

**Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system."**

I have already confirmed the obvious that the credentials are valid. Here is one of the snippets used. Any ideas what might have changed and how to fix? I can replicate the same issue on another system as well.

```
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($O365_username, $O365_password)
$context.Credentials = $creds

#Retrieve list
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)

#Get All items from the list and add the to the ListItems array
$ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())

$context.Load($List)
$context.Load($ListItems)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Is MFA enabled on the user account recently?

Comment: No MFA on the user.

Comment: It's possible that the legacy authentication was disabled in your tenant. It's not recommended, but this is how you can enable it:
`Connect-SPOService -Url –https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com
Set-SPOTenant –LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled $true`

Comment: Yeah, that could possibly be it, but certainly don't want to re-enable that for our tenant.